# How to get taxonomy category in permalink for each taxonomy OR How to give a parent page to a given taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, taxonomy, slug, blog-page

I have two taxonomies on my site: portfolio works and blog posts. I want blog posts under /blog and I want portfolio items under /work. I have created a page for blog posts and a page for portfolio works. "/blog" and "/work" are the URLs. This is because we want total control over these top-level pages and don't want to leave these to archive pages. This is all to deal with Google problems so we are trying to create a more clear site structure with specific content. We don't want to rely on archive pages

When I update my permalink structure to /blog/%postname%/ it works great except puts /blog in front the portfolio item's URL.

Q: How can I have this ONLY apply to blog posts and no other taxonomies?
or
Q: How can I specify a custom page to be the parent of each taxonomy? That's the real behavior I'm trying to get.

Info: Using completely up to date stand alone WordPress and the commercial theme "Brooklyn".

Note that The theme allows me to specify a "slug" as they call it for the custom taxonomy "portfolio" items, but then it replaces the /work page with an archive page by the same name. I am looking for a workaround either with a plugin or getting into some PHP is fine by me also.

Thank you everyone.

Edit, here are a bunch of links to things.

https://jugteam.com/blog/
https://jugteam.com/do-links-in-my-youtube-descriptions-provide-backlinks-and-seo-benefits/

https://jugteam.com/work/
https://jugteam.com/work/create-product-microsite/

(I don't know what a 'term index' is and google wasn't helpful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me (tested):

```php
add_action( 'init', static function () {
    register_taxonomy( 'portfolio-work', 'post', array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels'       => array(
            'name'          => 'Portfolio Works',
            'singular_name' => 'Portfolio Work',
        ),
        'rewrite'      => array(
            'slug'       => 'work',
            'with_front' => false,
        ),
    ) );
} );
```

Then created new pages titled "Blog" (slug: `blog`) and "Work" (slug: `work`), and was able to access the pages and taxonomy pages:

- Permalinks: `/blog/%postname%/`
- Page "Blog":
  `http://wpse417869.local/blog/`
- Post "Hello world!":
  `http://wpse417869.local/blog/hello-world/`
- Page "Work" (taxonomy index):
  `http://wpse417869.local/work/`
- Term "Portfolio Work A" in "Portfolio Work" taxonomy (term index):
  `http://wpse417869.local/work/portfolio-work-a/`